# Set an origin in an image and output coordinates of another point using matlab or other software

Tags: matlab

I am trying to find an easy way to find the distance (x,y coordinates) from one point(set at an origin) to another point(set arbitrarily) in an image.  Ideally, this would be matlab code that would allow two clicks on an image to set an origin and then a second point and then output the coordinates.  How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

the origin of the image coordinate system is in the top-left corner of the image at point(1,1) (not (0,0)). Anyway if you keep the origin this point or any other points and let's say you have the origin as P1(x1,y1), and the other point P2(x2,y2). No for calculating the distance between these points, you can use different metrics. Three famous metrics are:
Three famous metrics (to calculate the distance between two points):
1- Manhattan distance

```
d = abs(x1-x2) + abs(y1-y2)
```

2- Euclidean distance

```
d = sqrt((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2)
```

3- Minkowski distance

```
d = (abs(x1-x2)^c + abs(y1-y2)^c)^(1/c)
```

for more information about metric see these links [1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance), [2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manhattan_distance), [3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_distance).

In MATLAB you can use ginput function which provides the availability of selecting-pixel-by-mouse
so you first load your images and then select your points:

```
I = imread('c:\test.jpg');
imshow(I);
[X,Y] = ginput(2);
```

2 is the number of choosing the data (picking pixels from image), then you can use something like this:

```
d = ((X(1) - X(2)) ^ 2 + (Y(1) - Y(2)) ^ 2) ^ 0.5;
```

you can also use any other metrics....